# What is the definition of the "Apple Music API"?

Tags: ios, audio-player

I'm trying to understand the [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/) around the Apple Music API.  However, I can't seem to find a definition for the Apple Music API, and in particular how far it extends (i.e. how much of the entire [API](https://developer.apple.com/reference/) does it encompass?).

On [this iTune Affiliate Resource page](https://affiliate.itunes.apple.com/resources/documentation/apple-music-best-practices-for-app-developers/) it is suggested that the Apple Music API is a combination of:

- SKCloudServiceController
- MPMediaLibrary
- MPMusicPlayerController

Is this truly the definition of the Apple Music API? And in which case, if you use any of the frameworks listed above are you technically using the Apple Music API?

To put some context, I'm planning to build a music player that utilises a device's local library only. Is there a way of building such an iOS music player app and avoid using the Apple Music API?

Comment: Sorry, but can you explain why you would need to "avoid using the Apple Music API"? Nothing stops you from building a music player app so what's the problem?

Comment: Sure. In point 4.5.2 of the Review Guidelines, it says "Moreover, your app may not require payment or indirectly monetize access to the Apple Music service (e.g. in-app purchase, advertising, requesting user info)". This seems to suggest that building app that just needs to use a device's local library will unavoidably be classed as an app that uses the "Apple Music API". Hence, such an app can't be sold as such.

Comment: I don't think it suggests that at all. On the contrary, indeed, this is just the sort of thing your app will make no attempt to do. Don't worry, be happy.

Comment: Note, the critical part of guideline 4.5.2 is "your app may not require payment" - and my interpretation of this is the opposite of what you mentioned.

Comment: Not that this relates to the original question, but I am worrying about this point especially because I noticed on my phone that there seems to be no clear distinction between my iTune library and Apple Music songs when playing music in the standard Apple player or the app I've created.

Comment: "and my interpretation of this is the opposite of what you mentioned" Sure, if you quote a couple of words out of context you can make it mean anything you like. But in context, they are merely telling you that you can't require payment _for access to Apple Music_ — because _Apple_ is the one who gets the money for that. You are not doing that so just relax.

Comment: Valid point - I read the sentence as two different statements separated by an "or".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point of the language you quote in your comment is merely that you must not try to do what Apple is already doing, i.e. make money by getting the user to subscribe to or access Apple Music (the online streaming service) through *you* rather than Apple. You aren't going to do that, so don't worry about it.

**EDIT** I'll give you an example of what Apple is saying you cannot do. Let's say you have an app that plays music from the user's library, and that you differentiate: you say, to play *your* music is free, but play Apple Music songs will cost you an extra dollar of in-app payment. *That* would be a violation of the rules.

Comment: Your answer here is in relation to the comment - not the original question. I want to know the bounds of the "Apple Music API".

Comment: It is the API that accesses the Apple Music streaming service. You have already answered that part of the question yourself.

Comment: So by extension, to answer the question: "Is there a way of building such an iOS music player app and avoid using the Apple Music API?" - the answer seems to be "no".

Comment: You keep not listening. Take a deep breath and open your ears. There is nothing wrong with building an iOS music player app. I've got one. What you may not do is charge the user _to access Apple Music_ or make money from that user _accessing Apple Music in particular_. Accessing the music library in general, including in a paid app, is fine and always has been.

Comment: Thanks for your help - I'm definitely trying to understand what you are saying :). Extending on your edit, does that mean you don't have to "block out" Apple Music songs (since these can by default be included in the library) of your app that you may be selling?

Comment: I think you might have an easier time by concentrating on a different statement of the rules in https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines where they forbid "monetizing built-in capabilities provided by the hardware or operating system, such as Push Notifications, the camera, or the gyroscope; or Apple services, such as Apple Music access or iCloud storage." Have you ever used a paid app that uses the camera? or iCloud storage? Of course you have! There is an API _so that an app can do those things_.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I think while your answer doesn't answer the original questions, it does definitely answer the "root-cause questions" so to speak :)